# create page specific JavaScript while keeping it all in one global JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript file that is included into every page of my site.

I have this code below as part of that file.  This code however is only meant to work on 1 specific page and will not work on any other page of the site.

So when viewing other pages of the site my Console window will show this Error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null`

This is the sort of problem I run into often, what is a good way to wrap this code below into something to prevent this error from showing on all the other pages of my site that do not have the DOM elements that it is looking for?

Is it possibble to wrap this code block into a `Function` and then only call that function on the page that is needed somehow while keeping it al in this 1 Global JavaScript file?

```
// Add Fixed Header Bar on Tasks Edit View with a "Save" Button
var editTaskFixedHeaderBar = $('#task-edit-heading-row-labels');
var fixmeTop = editTaskFixedHeaderBar.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
        editTaskFixedHeaderBar.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0',
            left: '10'
        });
    } else {
        editTaskFixedHeaderBar.css({
            position: 'static'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you add a class to the body and then check if the page has that class and run the code only if the body has the class?

Comment: The error message pretty much gives the solution. First check if `editTaskFixedHeaderBar.offset()` is null. If it is, skip the rest of the code.

Comment: why dont you put the code for a specific page in a separate .js file ? an then in this page access it ?

Comment: Sorry guys i've been up writing code for going on 30 hours now....i'm not thinking at my best and shouldn't of posted this but it was too late to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in an if statement that checks to see if your element exists:

```
if ($('#task-edit-heading-row-labels').length > 0) {
    // The element exists... put your code here.
}
```

Basically $(...) will always return, without an error, regardless of what it found; if it found nothing, then its .length property will equal zero. So writing if ($(...).length > 0) is a neat way to handle page-specific stuff, or even just any situation where you aren't sure if some content exists or not, without having to tag your pages with classes or parse the URL, etc.

Comment: Thanks, i've been up over 24 hours, not thinking at my best...i've moved this code to a function, I just wasn't thinking about the fact that this if statement could still go inside my function....I was thinking backwards that I would have to basically check 2x one before calling function and another inside function...like I said wasn't thinking, thanks...will select this when time passes to allow me to do so

Comment: Epic! good luck with your project. I thought the downvotes a bit harsh - you asked a fair question. Now that we have easy access to JS build systems and can put all our JS in one file, there are issues about how to handle page-specific stuff... and if you haven't come across this idea of using $(...).length to check for stuff then you asked a reasonable question.

Comment: Thanks it was a silly basic question...from my experience on SO, when I ask a simple question like this, I get downvoted due to my experience and my Reputation score...as I have in the 12k range, i'm basically expected to do everything by the book as far as research well enough before asking a question as well as well documenting what I have tried and haven't tried, and most importantly, not ask basic questions like this that i'm expected to know the answer to...I agree to all of this but I deff get a kick out of doing it sometimes and getting the downvotes and rude off the wall comments...

Comment: I would like to come up with a good way to target specific pages, at least in the SugarCRM modules i'm working on, they don't have fancy SEO friend URL's so there are certain variables I have access to from $_GET with PHP so maybe I can target these with JS as well.  For example every page has an Action in the URL.... `index.php?module=module_name&action=ActionName` If I can target pages in JS with the `ActionName` then I think I might would be able to do page specific code in my main JS file

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I have actually used `$(...).length > 0` before but it seems there have been situation where it had not always worked